# variable interpolation for the variable saved as string

Tags: variables, tcl

I have can list for error where I want to interpolate the variable name inside the save string

eg

```
     dict set faultCode 1 "db connection failed \$dberr"
     dict set faultCode 2 "connection failed \$socketerr"

     set dberr "test"
     # should print "db conection failed test"
```

Now I want to interpolate the variable name in the dict or any way to do the same.

Comment: Thanks for asking. this question gave me new dimension of thinking in variable initialization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`subst`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/subst.htm)

```
dict set faultCode 1 "db connection failed \$dberr"
dict set faultCode 2 "connection failed \$socketerr"

set dberr "test"
puts [subst [dict get $faultCode 1]]
```

Comment: @made_in_india, note that you might consider passing `subst` `-nobackslashes` and `-nocommands` command-line options